# Blogger: Is post-preview URL stable?

Tags: blogger

I have written a Blogger post to report a security vulnerability in a popular online photo printing service. I have set an embargo (scheduled post) for this to go live on Tuesday at Noon.

There is a "preview URL" for this post similar to:

> https://privacylog.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=zdVaO00_____xGn0Ig&postId=279___342&type=POST

I would like to send this URL to the vendor in reference to the issue. Can I be assured that this URL will continue to work when they receive it and if they open it in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link won't work because it is a preview & for security purposes, a token is attached to the URL which is no longer valid

Answer (score 1):

Stable or not, preview links only works for people who have edit access to the post. So I doubt it will meet your needs.

Do you want them vendor to see the post in advance of your publishing it to the general public? If so, you could publish the post in a private blog, which you have invited them to read — or just email it to them.

Or if you want to share details with them only on the same day as everyone else, but want to pre-warn them that your post is coming — then you could just use the custom setting in the Links option in the post-editor to set what the URL will be, ie

```
www.yourBlog.blogspot.com/2015/05/yourCustomURLtext.html
```